# Group by and Pivot table in R

Tags: r, pivot, plyr

I'm just starting to learn R and transition a project from Jupyter Notebook to an R Markdown document. I have a data set that looks like this:

```
   DATE    | ROUTE | STOP_NAME   | BOARDING
-----------------------------------------------
2020-03-09 |  1    | STOP A      |  2
2020-03-09 |  1    | STOP B      |  3
2020-03-09 |  2    | STOP C      |  1
```

There are 20,xxx records over several days and 16 routes. I am trying to group by `DATE` and `ROUTE` and sum the `BOARDING` column. I was able to do this in Python using

```
df.groupby(['DATE','ROUTE'],as_index = False)['BOARDING'].sum().pivot('DATE','ROUTE').fillna(0)
```

I've been able to create a table in R close to what I want using:

```
groupcol1 <- c("DATE","ROUTE")
datacol1 <- ("BOARDING")
route_totals_table <- ddply(df,groupcol1,function(x) colSums(x[datacol1]))
```

But this gives me a table with a row for each date and route. I am wanting a table like this.

```
   DATE    | ROUTE 1 | Route 2  | Route 3
-----------------------------------------------
2020-03-09 |   25    | 45       |  10
2020-03-10 |   36    | 69       |  22
2020-03-11 |   95    | 100      |  29
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the tidyverse package to do this work, and the `spread` or `pivot_wider` functions from the tidyr package. Suppose your data is in a data.frame called "dat":

```
library(tidyverse)
# using spread
dat %>%
    mutate(ROUTE = paste0("Route ", ROUTE)) %>%
    group_by(DATE, ROUTE)%>%
    summarise(BOARDING = sum(BOARDING)) %>%
    spread(ROUTE, BOARDING)
# using pivot_wider
dat %>%
    mutate(ROUTE = paste0("Route ", ROUTE)) %>%
    group_by(DATE, ROUTE)%>%
    summarise(BOARDING = sum(BOARDING)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = ROUTE, values_from = BOARDING)
```

Both return:

```
  DATE          `Route 1` `Route 2`
  <chr>             <int>     <int>
1 "2020-03-09"          5         1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'd like to say that this worked but now I'm getting an error that the column 'ROUTE' doesn't exist. I can call the column using `df$ROUTE` and it shows up just fine.

Comment: is it possible there are spaces in the column names?

Comment: I've double checked and there are no spaces. I've checked in the .csv file and using `colnames(df)`. The code I wrote in the original question uses the route column and runs but does not return the desired output, but I have put quotes around the column names. Do you not need the quotes in R?

Comment: For this example, with the column names you have, you should not need quotes.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'll try to resolve the non-existing column issue.